# exchange two words using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to exchange two words in a line but it doesn't work. For example: "Today is my first day of university" should be "my is Today first day of university"

This is what I tried:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)/\3\2\1/' filename.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use an another separator as `'s#pat#repl#'`. For a more clearer command.

Answer (score 1):

I start to make it with `\s` which means any whitespaces chars.
I use it for match every words with `[^\s]*`which match with everything but not spaces.
And I had `\s*` for match withspaces between words. And don't forget to rewrite a space in replacement.

Look a this for an example:

```
sed 's#\([^ ]*\)\s+#\1 #'
```

( I use `#` instead of `/`)

Comment: You would need to use 1 or more instead of zero or more, otherwise you would match the empty string and the first space if the sentence starts with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -rn 's/(\w+\s)(\w+\s)(\w+\s)(.*)/\3\2\1\4/p' filename.txt
```

-n suppress automatic printing of pattern space

-r use extended regular expressions in the script

\s for whitespace

Comment: You would need to use 1 or more instead of zero or more, otherwise it would match the empty string and the first space if the sentence starts with whitespace for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/^(\w+)(\s+\w+\s+)(\w+)(.*)/\3\2\1\4/'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "Today is my first day of university"|sed -r 's/^(\w+)(\s+\w+\s+)(\w+)(.*)/\3\2\1\4/'                                                                           
my is Today first day of university
```

for your problem, awk is more straightforward:

```
awk '{t=$1;$1=$3;$3=t}1'
```

same input:

```
kent$  echo "Today is my first day of university"|awk '{t=$1;$1=$3;$3=t}1'                       
my is Today first day of university
```

Comment: The GNU sed version could be shortened by removing `(.*)` and `\4`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/\3 \2 \1/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not accounting for whitespace.

use [ \t]+ between words.

Comment: sed 's/\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)[\t]+\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)[\t]+\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)/\3\2\1/' filename.txt it's not working! :(

Comment: The `+` needs to be escaped: `sed 's/\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)[ \t]\+\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)[ \t]\+\([a-zA-z0-9]*\)/\3\2\1/' filename.txt`

Comment: I guess this will teach me not to answer too quickly.  The ultimate answer was that you did not account for whitespace in your original search string.  \w+ was what I was thinking of.  Thanks for the corrections.